# Focus issue when mixing JavaFX and Swing multiple times

Tags: java, swing, javafx, migration

If I embed Swing into embedded JavaFX which is embedded into Swing I do have issues with the focus of controls.

**Swing - JavaFX - Swing**

```
public EmbeddedTestWithFX() {
    setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(null);
    container.add(textArea);

    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        SwingNode swing = new SwingNode();
        StackPane stack = new StackPane(swing);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stack);
        swing.setContent(container);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> jfxPanel.setScene(scene));
    });

    setContentPane(jfxPanel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new EmbeddedTestWithFX().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

**Now I can see the TextArea but the issue is, It doesn't get the focus.**
If I register a FocusListener on the TextArea, I see that it becomes the focus after a click, but it loses the focus instantly.

But if I use:

`-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true`

the example starts to work. I can click now the TextArea, it holds the focos and I can enter text.

I really don't to use the VM parameter, because this is not an official supported VM feature, because it merges the two application threads of Swing and JavaFX. Do you know, how my example works without using the flag?

Comment: to check question(s)/answer(s) about by @kleopatra

Comment: Didn't found anything after 1 hour of searching - do you have a hint for me? @mKorbel

Comment: [e.g.___](http://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra?tab=questions)

Comment: Sorry but I don't find anything what solves my problem. Can you give me an explicit hint for my code-example? @mKorbel

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug. I filed it on Kenai Jira and got the repsonse, that it is going to be fixed in u40 - [RT-39196](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39196?)

As a workaround you can do:

```
    public EmbeddedTestWithFX() {
    setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(null);
    container.add(textArea);

    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    //WORKAROUND
    jfxPanel.setFocusable(false);

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        SwingNode swing = new SwingNode();
        StackPane stack = new StackPane(swing);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stack);
        swing.setContent(container);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> jfxPanel.setScene(scene));
    });

    setContentPane(jfxPanel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new EmbeddedTestWithFX().setVisible(true);
}
}
```